# How to know which device is on the website?

Tags: web, mobile, responsive-design

I recently made a javascript game, however, it refuses to work with phones and iPads...

Is there some way to know that whether the user is with a PC or not, so that I can prevent mobile users from trying it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting a mobile browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Answer (score -1):

You can use media query for the responsive UI and see the below code:

```
 // For Smartphone
            if (window.innerWidth < 600)
            {
                // TODO-- for the SmartPhone
            }

            // For Tablet
            else if(window.innerWidth > 600 && window.innerWidth < 768)
            {
                //TODO-- for the Tablet.
            }

            // For Desktop
            else if(window.innerWidth > 768)
            {
                //TODO -- for the Desktop.
            }
```